# I need help seeing my error with this code

Tags: javascript

I'm a newB teaching myself JS using JS is Sexy, among other things.  I'm struggling with one of the exercises and can't find my error. I researched and found this problem in a few places (including here) but none of those resolved my issue. I just get my title and footer when I run this.

I'll paste my code here to see if anyone can help me. Thanks, so much.

I hope I posted that right because it looks wierd.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 5 Example 8</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h2>Summary of Bookings</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

//CustomerBooking type

    function CustomerBooking(bookingId, customerName, film, showDate)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.bookingId = bookingId;
        this.showDate = showDate;
        this.film = film;
    }

    CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustomerName = function()
    {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustomerName = function(customerName)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    CustomerBooking.prototype.getShowDate = function()
    {
        return this.showDate;
    }
    CustomerBooking.prototype.setShowDate = function(showDate)
    {
        this.showDate = showDate;
    }
    CustomerBooking.prototype.getFilm = function()
    {
        return this.film;
    }
    CustomerBooking.prototype.setFilm = function(film)
    {
        this.film = film;
    }
    CustomerBooking.prototype.getBookingId = function()
    {
        return this.bookingId;
    }
    CustomerBooking.prototype.setBookingId = function(bookingId)
    {
         this.bookingId = bookingId;
        }

    //Cinema type

    function Cinema()
    {
        this.bookings = new Array();
    }

    Cinema.prototype.addBooking = function(bookingId, customerName, film, showDate)
    {
        this.bookings[bookingId] = new CustomerBooking(bookingId, customerName, film, showDate);
    }

    Cinema.prototype.getBookingsTable = function()
    {
        var booking;
        var bookingTableHTML =  "<table border=1>";

        for (booking in this.bookings)
        {
            bookingsTableHTML += "<tr><td>";
            bookingsTableHTML += this.bookings[booking].getBookingId();
            bookingsTableHTML += "</td>)"

            bookingsTableHTML += "<td>";
            bookingsTableHTML += this.bookings[booking].getCustomerName();
            bookingsTableHTML += "</td>;"

            bookingsTableHTML += "<td>";            
            bookingsTableHTML += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
            bookingsTableHTML += "</td>";

            bookingsTableHTML += "<td>";
            bookingsTableHTML += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
            bookingsTableHTML += "</td>";
            bookingsTableHTLM += "</tr>";
        }

        bookingsTableHTML += "</table>";
        return bookingsTableHTML;
    }   

    var londonOdeon = new Cinema();
    londonOdeon.addBooking(342, "Arnold Palmer", "Toy Story", "15 July 2009 20:15");
    londonOdeon.addBooking(335, "Louise Anderson", "The Shawshank Redemption", "27 July 2009 11:25");
    londonOdeon.addBooking(566, "Catherine Hughes", "Never Say Never", "27 July 2009 19:55");
    londonOdeon.addBooking(324, "Beci Smith", "Shrek", "29 Jluly 2009 20:15");

    document.write(londonOdeon.getBookingsTable()); 

</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more technical detail about your problem? What is the expected behavior of your code? What did you get instead? What have you tried?

Comment: @htoniv has mentioned your spelling mistake, I suggest you use some sort of Linter in the future (JSLint, ESLint, etc..), and strict mode you can more easily spot these issues.
Also you can debug through your code which should have easily spotted this mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is like this `var bookingTableHTML =  "<table border=1>";` but you are assigning into `bookingsTableHTML += "<tr><td>";` instead use  `bookingTableHTML += "<tr><td>";`

The mistake is `bookingTableHTML` but you are using `bookingsTableHTML`.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bigblind, MugiwaraUK, & htniv. I decided to change my var to bookingsTableHTML instead of changing everything else and it worked.  Had a big fight with JSLint(not very user friendly, yet).  I can now see my table with the showtimes.